# Null values for object properties de-serialized by WCF

Tags: c#, wcf, web-services, serialization, deserialization

I have a WCF web service that *used*  to work fine. Somewhere down the line it stopped and I cant tell why. The code and the interface never changed nor did the web.config (at least not in relation to the web services section). I have a class:

```
[DataContract]
public class QuizServiceArgs
{
    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 1)] 
    public int Category1 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 2)] 
    public int Category2 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 3)] 
    public int Category3 { get; set; }

    [DataMember(IsRequired = true, Order = 4)] 
    public int Category4 { get; set; }
}
```

And the service interface is simple:

```
public interface IQuizService
{
    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
       BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,
       ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
    ServiceResult Save(QuizServiceArgs answers, string strvalue, int intvalue);
}
```

The second two params `strvalue` and `intvalue` were added only for troubleshooting to see if those were getting deserialized -- and they are. When I hit the service, I get an error saying that I'm missing the `Category1` parameter from the request but as you can see this Fiddler screenshot, the values are there.

[image: fiddler screenshot]

**I can get primitive values to pass in but objects seem to all be instantiated with null or default values. What am I doing wrong?**

## UPDATE

I never actually got my original question answered which sucks, but Sixto suggested that I switch my serialization to JSON. JSON was the original design but got nixed when I was having trouble with it. After I successfully switched back to JSON, everything was serializing and deserializing properly. Now I am just waiting for this to break for no explanation so I can switch back to XML....

Comment: by the way, i cropped out some headers from the fiddler request that i considered to be noise. dont worry if there isnt a Content-length attribute in the pic, there was one in the request :)

Comment: Did you change the Order property on the data-member attributes? Or any namespaces? Or remove any members?

Comment: @Marc The attributes are the same order in the POST as they are specified in the code. I don't have any namespaces - I've kept it empty in other projects and it worked okay. I did not remove any members. That is literally my entire `QuizServiceArgs` class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The DataMember **IsRequired** attribute tells the WCF deserializer to expected an element in the message XML with that name (at least it does for soap deserialization). It sounds like the client code that is generating the message request is no longer sending all the Category... elements. It doesn't mean you can't send a null value for a DataMember marked IsRequired, it just means the element needs to exist in the message.

UPDATE: looking at the XML more closely, shouldn't there be a QuizServiceArgs element in the XML?

Comment: I'm not actually to the point of client code yet. I used Fiddler to manually craft my request. In the screenshot, you can see that the CategoryX values are in the XML schema that is sent to the server. I understand that the server thinks I'm not sending those properties. I just don't know why it thinks that.

Comment: I'm not too familiar with how the XML should look like for WebInvoke but the error message is saying that the deserializer is not finding the Category... elements before it hits the answers element end tag.

Comment: Actually I think the main issue is that you set the WebInvoke formatter to json instead of XML :)

Comment: The response is JSON. The request is defaulted to XML. I would have preferred the request and response both be JSON but I was having trouble getting the request to work for JSON and just left it at XML for simplicity's sake. Maybe its time to revisit the JSON request.

Comment: Re: "QuizServiceArgs element in the XML" the XML tags need to match the parameter names, not the parameter types. So `<answers>` inthe XML corresponds to `QuizServiceArgs answers` in the C# signature.

Comment: You didnt directly answer my question but I got everything to work by switching everything over to JSON instead of mixing JSON and XML. I had all AJAX requests passing through my wrapper ajax function so modifying everything across the application was easy. Thanks.

Answer (score 8):

You have a namespace issue. By default, when you create an interface for the servicecontract, it assigns it a namespace. Namespace is like scope for the SOAP xml elements, and if it doesn't fall under the same scope, it thinks it doesn't exist. Chances are the code that posts stoppped providing the namespace(?). You have to refer by it when posting the XML - but I'm not entirely sure what it assigns(something server specific), so it is good practice to always define a namespace, like so:

```
[ServiceContract(Namespace = "your namespace")]
public interface IQuizService 
{     
     [OperationContract]     
     [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",        
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.WrappedRequest,        
            ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]     
            ServiceResult Save(QuizServiceArgs answers, string strvalue, 
                int intvalue); 
}
```

And then the posts should have the namespace in the SOAP request.

```
<Save xmlns="your namespace">.....</Save>
```

The namespace should also match your service declaration in web.config.

Also need it in the datacontract

`[DataContract(Namespace = "your namespace")]`

Comment: I added a namespace to the three places: ServiceContract on the interface, root node of the request and the endpoint bindingNamespace in the web.config. Same response. I have used WCF without the namespace before without problems so I'm not terribly surprised that I'm still having the problem.

Comment: I'm still fairly certain its a namespace issue. As I mentioned, there is a default one assigned, which if matches up should work fine. Oh, and you also need in the datacontract - [DataContract(Namespace = "your namespace")]. They all have to line up to work...

Comment: You've just saved me a lot of time! A bounty of 300 on the way to you M.R.