# HttpWebREquest XMLSerialzation POST request sending partially null properties to REST service

Tags: c#, xml-serialization, httpwebrequest

I implemented a method which makes POST request to my REST services. It serializes the passed object using XML serialization, but at server side half of the properties become null, and first 3 properties retain values.

I checked all class property well decorated with XMLElement attribute. Calling this method with smaller size (three property ) works fine, but when I pass class-object with 7/8 property it causes above mentioned problem. Here is my method: (This code is being written for .NET Compact framework 3.5, though I copy paste the same code to .NET 4.0 class library project, and it is giving me same error. So Compact Framework doesn't seem to be an issue) .

```
  public static  object Post<T>(string uri, T paramObj)
    { 
        string baseURI = InfraHelper.BaseURI;

        HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(baseURI + uri);

        req.Method = "POST";
        req.ContentType = "application/xml; charset=utf-8";
        req.Timeout = 30000;
        req.AllowWriteStreamBuffering = true;

        Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);

        using (System.IO.StreamWriter sw = new System.IO.StreamWriter(req.GetRequestStream(), enc))
        {
            XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://www.123insight.com/InsightHandHeldDeviceSvc");                

            serializer.Serialize(sw, paramObj);
            sw.Flush();                
        }

        HttpWebResponse resp = (HttpWebResponse)req.GetResponse();

        // Retrieve response stream and wrap in StreamReader
        string strResp = string.Empty;
        using (Stream respStream = resp.GetResponseStream())
        {
            StreamReader rdr = new StreamReader(respStream);
            strResp = rdr.ReadToEnd();
            rdr.Close();
        }

        XElement xDoc = XElement.Parse(strResp);
        XNamespace ns = xDoc.Name.Namespace;

        var node = from compileItem in xDoc.Elements(ns + "Value")
                   select compileItem.Value;


        return node.First().ToString();

    }
```

My Service method is well-decorated

```
 [OperationContract]
        [WebInvoke(Method = "POST",
            UriTemplate = "AdjustStock",
            RequestFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
           ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Xml,
            BodyStyle = WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare)]
        public PostResponse AdjustStock(AdjustStockRequestDTO adjStockDTO)
        {
```

Many Thanks for any help friends, my whole day wasted here :(
I also tried with specifying req.ContentLength = length; to figure out the length I used following method:-

```
Encoding enc = new UTF8Encoding(false);
            XmlSerializer serializer1 = new XmlSerializer(typeof(T), "http://www.xxx.com/xxx");    
            StringWriter sw1 = new StringWriter();
            serializer1.Serialize(sw1, paramObj);
            string data = sw1.ToString();
            sw1.Close();

            byte[] byteArray = enc.GetBytes(data);
            int length = byteArray.Length;
```

rest of the code is same as above. Now it is failing with timeout exception, and call is not reaching to server..

Comment: Why are you using HttpWebRequest to call a WCF service instead of using the generated client proxy?

Comment: Hi Darin, Client is .NET Compact Framework Version 3.5, and ChannelFactory not available with CF :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

WCF REST usage of XML has some De-serialization issues.
i switched to JSON.
for .NET CF 3.5 I am using solution from http://json.codeplex.com/ (3.5 release for CF)
and it is working fine for me.

Following Thread help me to go Json way:-
[Null values for object properties de-serialized by WCF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5860379/null-values-for-object-properties-de-serialized-by-wcf)

Not sure why such obvious XML- Desalinization should have such issue on WCF-REST service side.
Also this issue was not CF specific, as REST svc was hosted at server, and I tried calling using same method with normal WinForm client.
If anybody has better answer...meanwhile JSON rocks

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare Order for DataMember attributes in DataContract. This is necessary if your client is sending xml request. 
for example

```
  [Serializable]
  [DataContract(Namespace = Utils.DataNamespace)]
  public class Detail 
  {
    [DataMember(Order = 1)] 
    public string LineNbr { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 2)]
    public string UPC { get; set; }

    [DataMember(Order = 3)] 
    public string SkuNbr { get; set; }
 }
```